# How to downsample time-series data with a float downsampling factor with decimate scipy

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have 2 Sensors that are collecting time-series data that I am trying to align.

```
sensorOneData = np.random.rand(50)

sensorTwoData = np.random.rand(180)
```

Sensor one is sampling at a rate of `50` Hz, and sensor 2 is sampling at a rate of `180` Hz.

Supposedly, to align sensor two’s data with sensor one’s data. I would need to downsample by a factor of `3.6`

Normally I would use `scipy.signal.decimate(sensorTwoData,downSampleFactor)`, although decimate only supports integer downsampling factors.

I've tried `scipy.signal.resample(sensorTwoData, sensorOneData.shape[0])` as an alternative method, but the results are not entirely correct as it does not apply an anti-aliasing filter.

Are there alternatives in downsampling with a float number downsampling factor that produces the desired processed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [resampy](https://resampy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
import resampy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# after resampling one frequency should be gone
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*150*np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)) \
        + np.sin(2*np.pi*50*np.linspace(0, 1, 1000))
resampled_signal = resampy.resample(signal, 1000, 200)


plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 499, 500), np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal))[:500])
# below scaling to have same energy in spectrum
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 99, 100), np.abs(np.fft.fft(resampled_signal))[:100] * 1000/200, 'r--')
plt.legend(['before resampling', 'after resampling'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried out the implementation, and the results seem satisfactory!